# Да и вообще (,) нет места на теле, которое не могло бы по-настоящему от чего-то страдать

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

Да и вообще(,) нет места на теле, которое не могло бы по-настоящему от чего-то страдать.

- Можно ли здесь обособить сочетание "да и вообще"? В правилах говорится о "да и вообще" как о присоединительном союзе, не требующим обособления "справа". Но здесь контекст, в котором "да и вообще" начинает выполнять функцию вводного слова.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Могу только привести статистику. 345 из 1223 подобных вхождений в Нацкорпусе содержат запятую. Пример:

> Да и вообще, что это мы с вами затеяли? [Ю. О. Домбровский. Факультет ненужных вещей, часть 3 (1978)]

Answer (score 1):

Если вводное, то запятая ставится. Но может быть и не вводным, а обстоятельством.
*Да и вообще нет места...* – то есть *совсем* нет места.